# Efficiently transform pandas dataFrame using column name as factor

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to transform a DataFrame given by a software into a more python usable one and I can't fix it in a simple way with pandas because I have to use information contained in the columns. Here a simple example :

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'00' : [1],'01' : [11], '10': [111], '11':[1111]}
pd.DataFrame(d)

    00  01   10    11
 0   1  11  111  1111
```

The column names contains the factors that I need to use in rows, I would like to get something like this :

```
df = {'trt': [0,0,1,1], 'grp': [0,1,0,1], 'value':[1,11,111,1111]}
pd.DataFrame(df)

   grp  trt  value
0    0    0      1
1    1    0     11
2    0    1    111
3    1    1   1111
```

Any ideas of how to do it properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) created [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) and transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.str[0], df.columns.str[1]])
print (df)
   0        1      
   0   1    0     1
0  1  11  111  1111

df1 = df.T.reset_index()
df1.columns = ['grp','trt','value']
print (df1)
  grp trt  value
0   0   0      1
1   0   1     11
2   1   0    111
3   1   1   1111
```

Similar solution with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) and rename `index`:

```
d = {'00' : [1],'01' : [11], '10': [111], '11':[1111]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.str[0], df.columns.str[1]])
print(df.rename_axis(('grp','trt'), axis=1).rename(index={0:'value'}).T.reset_index())
  grp trt  value
0   0   0      1
1   0   1     11
2   1   0    111
3   1   1   1111
```

Comment: Super, glad can help you! Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

To me the simplest solution is just melting the original frame and splitting the column names in a second step. Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
mf = pd.melt(df)
mf[['grp', 'trt']] = mf.pop('variable').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(tuple(x)))
```

Here's `mf` after melting:

```
  variable  value
0       00      1
1       01     11
2       10    111
3       11   1111
```

And the final result, after splitting the variable column:

```
   value grp trt
0      1   0   0
1     11   0   1
2    111   1   0
3   1111   1   1
```

I'd encourage you to read up more on melting here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html . It can be incredibly useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice I will look closer to the melt function